# How to take a step back while looping through a range in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to make a password generator where you input the number of letters, symbols and numbers you would like in the password. I have to do it in a random order. I have a solution in mind (see below) but it requires me to 'go back a step' in a `for` loop. I know that using a `while` loop would be far easier, but for undisclosed reasons I have to use a for loop. Here is the relevant code:

```
for i in range(1, letters_left + numbers_left + symbols_left + 1):  
  char = random.randint(0, 2)
  
  if char == 0:
      if letters_left:
        final_string += (letters[random.randint(0, 25)])
        letters_left -= 1
      else:
        i -= 1
        
  if char == 2:
      if symbols_left:
        final_string += (symbols[random.randint(0, 8)])
        symbols_left -= 1
      else:
        i -= 1
        
  if char == 3:
    if numbers_left:
        final_string += (numbers[random.randint(0, 9)])
        numbers_left -= 1
    else:
      i -= 1
```

You can see that I've tried subtracting from `i`, but it doesn't work. I've already read up a bit and it seems that in python `for` loops use the `__next__()` method (?) to 'go forward'. Is there a similar method (again, ?) which 'goes backwards'? I'm new to python.

Comment: Maybe set `range(...)` to a variable `range`, and then access the last item using `range[i - 1]` ?

Comment: good idea, but I tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So no while loop today:

```
import random
import sys

final_string = ""

letters = []
for c in range(65, 65+26):
    letters.append(chr(c))

numbers = []
for c in range(48, 58):
    numbers.append(chr(c))

symbols = []
for c in range(97, 106):
    symbols.append(chr(c))

letters_left = 2
numbers_left = 3
symbols_left = 4

LETTER = 0
SYMBOL = 1
NUMBER = 2

left = []
for i in range(0, letters_left):
    left.append(LETTER)

for i in range(0, symbols_left):
    left.append(SYMBOL)

for i in range(0, numbers_left):
    left.append(NUMBER)

def build(list):
    
    ret = ""
    size = len(list)

    if size == 0:
        return ret

    now = 0

    if size > 1:
        now = random.randint(0, 4321) % size

    char = list.pop(now)

    if char == LETTER:
        ret += (letters[random.randint(0, 25)])
        
    elif char == SYMBOL:
        ret += (symbols[random.randint(0, 8)])
        
    else: 
        ret += (numbers[random.randint(0, 9)])

    return ret + build(list)

final_string = build(left)

print (final_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
import random

final_string = ""

letters = []
for c in range(65, 65+26):
    letters.append(chr(c))

numbers = []
for c in range(48, 58):
    numbers.append(chr(c))

symbols = []
for c in range(97, 106):
    symbols.append(chr(c))

letters_left = 1

numbers_left = 1

symbols_left = 1

left = [letters_left, symbols_left, numbers_left]

print (left)

for i in range(1, letters_left + numbers_left + symbols_left + 1):

    char = -1
    while char == -1:
        c = random.randint(0, 2)
        if left[c] > 0:
            char = c
  
    print(char)

    if char == 0:
        final_string += (letters[random.randint(0, 25)])
        left[0] -=1
        
    elif char == 1:
        final_string += (symbols[random.randint(0, 8)])
        left[1] -=1
        
    else: 
        final_string += (numbers[random.randint(0, 9)])
        left[2] -=1

print (final_string)
```

Comment: this is going to sound pedantic, but I need a solution without any ```while``` loops. also, this doesn't really answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Probably not (at least without using code far beyond me). BUT: Instead of trying to 'go back', I extended the array that I was looping through. The idea was, I would keep extending the array for as many iterations that I had to, until I didn't so the loop would break. It is, in effect, a while loop. Here is the code:

```
for i in count_arr:  
  char = random.randint(0, 2)
  
  if char == 0:
      if letters_left:
        final_string += (letters[random.randint(0, 25)])
        letters_left -= 1
        
  if char == 1:
      if symbols_left:
        final_string += (symbols[random.randint(0, 8)])
        symbols_left -= 1
        
  if char == 2:
    if numbers_left:
        final_string += (numbers[random.randint(0, 9)])
        numbers_left -= 1

  if letters_left + numbers_left + symbols_left == 0:
    incomplete = 0

  if incomplete == 1:
    count_arr.append("cont.")
```